# Undoing upvotes for comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, comments

Is there any way to undo upvotes for comments, like upvotes and downvotes for normal questions and answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to undo an upvote that is done to a comment.

[The request to allow this functionality is also declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment). Comment upvotes are very minor in impact in the grand scheme of things, they don't even affect reputation. As such, the *need* for reversing an upvote is very minor.

Comment: what about the flag button? it goes away when you do an upvote

Comment: Likewise, the upvote button goes away when you flag. They're exclusive operations.

Comment: They shouldn't be exclusive when the comment is edited.  And I can imagine a scenario where the flag button is intended to be clicked and the upvote is hit instead.  The flag button doesn't disappear on questions/answers when you upvote.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - As of April 2012 - It is possible to undo comment upvotes (some limitations apply - the primary use case is to undo an accidental click). According to [waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/179041), former employee at Stack Exchange:

> 1. You can un-upvote a comment within the first 60 seconds, provided you did not navigate away.
> 2. Once you un-upvote a comment you can not upvote it again.
>
> We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past. The only use case is undoing a mis-click.
>
> Here's what it looks like when you start to unupvote a comment:
>
> [image: Popup: Are you sure you want to undo your upvote?]
>
> Then if you try to upvote the same comment again:
>
> [image: You've already undone your upvote; you cannot upvote again]